# Align checkbox with label in middle of first sentence

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to align a checkbox that has certain styling with the label to the right of it, in such a way that a multi line label aligns on the center of the checkbox. I cannot modify HTML, only the CSS.

This is the checkbox:

```html
<style>
  input[type='checkbox'] {
    color: rgb(64, 62, 63);
    display: block;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 19.1953px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-right: 8.8px;
    margin-top: -1.6px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 19.1953px;
  }
  span {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(64, 62, 63);
    cursor: default;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    position: static;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
</style>
<div style="max-width:200px; margin-top: 20px">
    <label style="display: flex; align-items: baseline">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <span>A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The result is:

[image: checkbox not aligned]

What I want is the text to be in line with the first sentence. `align-items: center` does not work since although it aligns single line labels perfectly, multi line labels are aligned on the center instead of the first line.

Desired:

[image: desired]

Is there a way to accomplish this?

See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/transducer/pen/abEyqOv) for an example.

Comment: Does align-items: top on the label give what  you need?

Comment: @AHaworth thanks, no it does not. [`align-items: top` is not available in the description of Mozilla?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `align-self: start;`

Because of your label element has flexBox and has `align-items` on it in HTML, you can use `align-self` to override  `align-items` property and move position of element horizontally.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  color: rgb(64, 62, 63);
  display: block;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 19.1953px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 8.8px;
  margin-top: -1.6px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 19.1953px;
  align-self: start;
}
```

EDIT

Can you try this one please. Only play with`margin-top: 1px;`

you may probably need

```
.input{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  
}


  input[type='radio'] {
    color: rgb(64, 62, 63);
    display: block;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 19.1953px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 32px; 
    margin-right: 8.8px;
    margin-top: 1px; 
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 19.1953px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="max-width:200px; margin-top: 20px">
      <label style="display: flex; align-items: baseline">
          <input type="radio"></input>
          A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text
          A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text A long text
      </label>

      <label style="display: flex; align-items: baseline">
        <input type="radio"></input>
        A long text 
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in my distilled example, but not in the actual code base... There even with `align-self: start` the checkbox is still higher up https://i.imgur.com/f6GYezD.png. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please add information to reproduce that issue @ErwinRooijakkers need to check text properties too which is <span> inside your HTML

Comment: I've added the properties to the span and extended the question! See https://codepen.io/transducer/pen/abEyqOv.

Comment: it seems to be the `line-height: 32px;` property on the span. Otherwise your `align-self: start` works fine. Only I don't know where this computed value comes from. Turning it into `line-height: 2em` brings the same problem back. But setting it to 0px makes line go over each others.

Comment: changing `line-height` is not a good approach.  I added a snippet @ErwinRooijakkers